# How to implement the label click event

Tags: javascript, dojo, click, label

I need to perform the some action in my label click event in dojo AMD module, but when i click the labe not fire in my function. My sample code is given below

```
 dom.byId("My label Id").on("click", function (evt) { // not fire here
     my function();
    });
```

Comment: Is this on mobile? If so, add a dummy `onclick=""` to the label

Comment: Any error in the console? Do you not need dojo/dom to call dom.byId?

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/byId.html

Answer (score 1):

Try to register the onClick like :

```
 require(["dojo/on",
   "dojo/dom",
   "dijit/registry",
   "dojo/domReady!"],
    function (on, dom, registry) {

  on(dom.byId("MylabelId"), "click", function(e){
    // handle the event
     dom.byId("thisIsClicked").innerHTML = "I have done it!";
  });
 });
```

Here's the Fiddle for my Example above: http://jsfiddle.net/y59QZ/10/

And a Tip for your VariableNames - don't use Whitespaces in the Names - write it without or if you must take an underscore. But Whitespaces in Variablenames are a NoGo!

Regards, Miriam